# how to find XPath for elements which consist javascript in it attributes?

Tags: javascript, xpath, automation

We have below HTML code in our application Home Page, I have to locate element '**Dimensions**' which is Hyperlink and available in Table has Java Script (as per my understanding, though I am not in programming background) source code in it.

Could someone please help me out to finding Xpath?

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" id="categoryDetails">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
        <h3 style="font-size: 0px;">Dimensions</h3>
        <a id="y5ev2rb" title="Display Dimensions Category" href="javascript:triggerTransition('//Category/dimensions')" tabindex="1001">Dimensions</a> - This contains all the dimension links.
    </td>
</tr>                           
<tr>
    <td>
        <h3 style="font-size: 0px;">Consolidations</h3>
        <a id="zf3cj7z" title="Display Consolidations Category" href="javascript:triggerTransition('//Category/consolidations')" tabindex="1002">Consolidations</a> - This contains all the consolidation links.
    </td>
</tr>                           
<tr>
    <td>
        <h3 style="font-size: 0px;">Budget Forms</h3>
        <a id="zcuvnu5" title="Display Budget Forms Category" href="javascript:triggerTransition('//Category/budgetForm')" tabindex="1003">Budget Forms</a> - This contains all the Budget Form links.
    </td>
</tr>                                                       
</tbody></table>
```

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vofDq.jpg)

Comment: can you please add the HTML in your question instead of an image

Comment: Please include your code as a Code Sample (`{}`) in your Question. [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: Why don't you just find it by the ID?  It's clearly listed with an ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
/table/tbody/tr/td/a[.='Dimensions']
```